# Title and Subtitle getting mixed up

Tags: css

I have a title and subtitle displaying in a div.
I am facing an issue when either of the title or subtitle are longer they get mixed up otherwise with shorter titles and subtitles its not an issue.

To display the title my css is

```
.sch-task-name {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

and to display subtitle

```
.sch-tool-text-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: -44px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    color: blue;
}

.sch-task-inner {
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 27px 2px 7px 8px;
}

.sch-tool-ct {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="sch-task-inner">
   <span class="sch-task-name"> Ticket Under Needs Information 2</span>
   <div class="sch-tool-ct">
      <span class="sch-tool-text-activity">Kanban Deliverable</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here sch-task-name displays title and sch-tool-text-activity displays subtitle.

I am new to css and dont know much of it.

Would appreciate any help!Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well please?

Comment: I second the above. It's difficult to know without seeing the HTML.

Comment: you should remove the **top:-44px;** as described here https://jsfiddle.net/taos7ots/

Comment: thanks @ymz but I want sch-tool-text-activity (Kanban deliverbale) to be displayed before on top of sch-task-name , and I cannot change the HTML sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get sch-task-name to display underneath sch-tool-text-activity without rearranging the content in the HTML, then you may want to use the **order property** of flexible items.

You'll need to set the parent container's display to **'display:flex'** first. Then, since you want them to stack, you'll have to allow the items to flow onto multiple links by setting **'flex-wrap:wrap'** (still on the parent container). Lastly, you'll set the order of the spans to **'order:1'** and **'order:2'** to rearrange their order, with '1' displaying first.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ph0rn16w/1/

```
.sch-task-name {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size:20pt;
    order:2;
}

.sch-tool-text-activity {
    position: relative;
    //top: -44px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    color: blue;
}

.sch-task-inner {
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 27px 2px 7px 8px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.sch-tool-ct {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    order:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pandy Also I have one more text to be displayed after sch-task-name then what should I set in its class?

Comment: You should be able to order that text in the same way as the previous two - unless there's anything special about the container you have it in or that sort of thing. If you run into problems, post the updated HTML/CSS you're using and I can take a look :)